# Map components are not reflecting

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I'm learning React JS.Trying to map components by calling data from external JS file.
There is no error or issue in the code.

This is **content.jsx** inside the **/src/component** folder.Here I'm rendering mapped components from App.jsx.

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Content(props) {
    <div>
        <p> {props.name} </p>
        <p> {props.rollNo} </p>
    </div>
}
```

This is **App.jsx** inside the **src** folder

```
import React from 'react';
import Content from './component/content';
import Data from './Data'

export default function App() {
    const jokeElements =  Data.map( (ele) => {
        return(
            <Content name={ele.name} rollNo={ele.rollNo} />
        );
    })
  
    return(
        <div>
            {jokeElements}
        </div>
    )
    
}
```

and rendering **App.js** to **index.js** which is in **src** folder. The data.js contains data in **src** folder.

Data.js file:

```
const Data=[
    {
        name:"Deepak",
        rollNo:"123"
    },
    {
        name:"Yash",
        rollNo:"124"
    },
    {
        name:"Raj",
        rollNo:"125"
    },{
        name:"Rohan",
        rollNo:"126"
    },
    {
        name:"Puneet",
        rollNo:"127"
    
    },
    {
        name:"Vivek",
        rollNo:"128"
    },
    {
        name:"Aman",
        rollNo:"129"
    },
    ]
    export default Data;
```

The issue I can output other JSX elements, but I'm not able to display mapped components. What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: Content component doesn't return anything.

Comment: Yup that's  the mistake, kicking myself for it

Answer (score 1):

Im guessing that "Content" component is the "Joke" component, if so, it has no return statement, try:

```
export default function Joke(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p> {props.name} </p>
      <p> {props.rollNo} </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yeah corrected it, but still it's displaying blank page

Comment: So simply create reproducible example in any sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

You need a return statement in Joke function of content.js